# How to fix the screen size for a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a tangent function (see below) and am trying to stop the plot 'jumping around':

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lowerBound = 0

plt.ion()

while True:
    x = np.arange(lowerBound, lowerBound + 50, 0.1)
    y = np.tan(x / 2)

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.pause(0.01)

    lowerBound += 1
```

I tried

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
```

and

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(4)
```

but they just made the plot smaller, instead of fixing the height.

I was thinking I could do:

`set y to maximum of -200 and y` and `set y to minimum of 200 and y`,
but I don't know how to get the min/max for all items in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the plot from 'jumping around', you can use plt.ylim() like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lowerBound = 0

plt.ion()

while True:
    x = np.arange(lowerBound, lowerBound + 50, 0.1)
    y = np.tan(x / 2)

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.ylim(-200, 200) # <---
    plt.pause(0.01)

    lowerBound += 1
```